# JQuery UI Slider Change not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm fairly confident I'm missing something simple but no googling has revealed what that might be. Not sure why, but the change event on the jquery ui slider widget is not firing. You can inspect the element and see that the input is being converted to a widget but it's not having any effect. I've duplicated my results in jsfiddle which almost guarantees this is user error. Anyone have any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/ut8zg056/

html:

```
        <div id="volume_master_container" class="volumeContainer">
            M<br>
            <input type="range" class="volumeSlider" data-target="" id="volume_master" orient="vertical">
        </div>
```

js:

```
    $(".volumeSlider").slider({
        change: function(event, ui) {
            console.log("changing");
        }
    });
```

== EDIT ==

As J08691 pointed out below, I didn't realize slider() needed to be bound to a div vs an input. Everything functions as expected when applied correctly.

Comment: This works for me: `$(".volumeSlider").change(function(){
console.log("changing");
})`

Comment: `$(".volumeSlider").slider().change(function() { console.log("changing"); })`. Looking at the jQuery UI docs for slider, they seem to require it be bound to a div and not an input, so you'd need to attach the change event separately to your input.

Comment: @j08691 Thank you, that was my problem. I didn't realize that these needed to be bound to a div vs the input.